# angularjs 1.x, resource unexplained memory leak in google chrome, when making requests

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-chrome, memory-leaks

Here is the problem, when running smth like this http://jsbin.com/kirikowujo/1/edit?html,console,output

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html data-ng-app="app">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.6/angular.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.6/angular-resource.js"></script>
  <title>JS Bin</title>
  <script>

var app = angular.module('app', ['ngResource']);

    app.controller('main',['$scope','$interval','srv',function($scope,$interval,srv){

       $interval(function(){
         srv.test({},function(ret){

       console.log(ret.args.a);
     });


       },5000);
      $scope.aa='dd';
    }]);


    app.factory('srv', ['$resource',
    function ($resource) {
        return $resource('https://httpbin.org/get', {}, {
            test: {method: 'GET', params: {'a':1}},

        });
    }]);
  </script>
</head>
<body data-ng-controller="main">
  {{aa}}
</body>
</html>
```

the used memory of the browser slowly starts increasing and i can't seem to figure out why. It gets so bad that the whole OS gets laggy. 
When i open the chrome task manager, the process "Browser" takes all the memory, not the open tab process. This happens on Chrome 64.0.3282.140 (Official Build) (64-bit) on Ubuntu. 
Does anyone see any problem with this code and where the memory leak may be coming from?

Comment: I would try cache true/false and `$scope.on('$destroy', stopInterval)`

Comment: tried with cache:false, it didn't work still the memory gets used and not released. The on $destroy is when the controller is destroyed, but in this case it never gets destroyed, and it shouldn't get destroyed.